# DyanmoDBLocal on a different container in Docker

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, docker-compose

Is it possible to run DynamoDBLocal on a different container in Docker and then access it from a different Container running a nodejs app?  My problem is that I have the following Docker Compose file

```
version: '2'
services:
  DynamoDBLocal:
    container_name: DynamoDBLocal
    build:
      context: ./DynamoDBLocal
    image: tag/drive-sync/dynamodb:latest
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
  SetupService:
    build:
      context: ./setup
    image: tag/drive-sync/setup_service:latest
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
```

When I try to access the DynamoDBLocal container from the nodejs app on SetupService I get the following error

"message": "Inaccessible host: `dynamodblocal'. This service may not be available in the`us-west-2' region.",

Answer (score 0):

Did it ever worked outside of Docker?

Sounds to me like you're not passing a correct [Endpoint](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB.html#endpoint-property) when constructing your DynamoDB requests in Node.

Can you edit and add how you construct the DynamoDB object? It should look like: `http://dynamodblocal:8000`

Also, Docker-compose standard is that services names be all lower caps.

Comment: this is exactly what I used. http://dynamodblocal:8000, I think anything not localhost it tries to connect directly to AWS.

Comment: just to clarify, did you add http://? Otherwise I believe the SDK will try to use HTTPS